# Change location of pages in sitecore

Tags: .net, sitecore

I want to change location of page in sitecore when it changed. I use event OnItemSaved. And I have a question. How get fields from this page (`Article_Date`) and change position of page. 
I have pages like this:

- 2012

  - Article from 2012
- 2013

And if i change date of article to 2013 i want to see this page in category `2013`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `MoveTo()` method:

```
protected void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (args == null)
        return;

    Item pageToMove = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;

    Item item2013 = pageToMove.Database.GetItem("/sitecore/content/...PathTo2013");

    pageToMove.MoveTo(item2013);      
}
```

Assuming that you have structure

```
- 2012
    - Article 1
    - Article 2
    - Article 3
    -  ...
- 2013
    - Article m
    - Article n
```

the code for moving can look like this:

```
protected void OnItemSaved(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    if (args == null)
        return;

    Item pageToMove = Event.ExtractParameter(args, 0) as Item;

    Item item2013 = pageToMove.Database.GetItem(pageToMove.Parent.Parent.Paths.FullPath+ "/" + DateTime.Now.Year);

    pageToMove.MoveTo(item2013);      
}
```

Comment: hm... I have `sender object` and `EventArgs args`. How get new Date and the item where we put it all